# Multibranch pipeline with jenkinsfile in svn:external

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have set up a multibranch pipeline job for a repository in SVN. Since I want to keep the jenkinsfiles the same in all branches, they are not really located in the branches, but in a different location and only referenced via svn:externals.

Unfortunately the multibranch pipeline does not seem to follow these references and doesn't find the jenkinsfiles (the paths are correctly set):

```
Checking candidate branch /branches/aaa/bbb/ccc@HEAD
      ‘ddd\eee\fff\jenkinsfile' not found
Does not meet criteria
```

Is there any way to tell Jenkins and the multibranch-pipeline plugin setup to also follow svn:externals when looking for the jenkinsfiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Jenkins is trying to get the Jenkinsfile with a lightweight checkout which does not consider svn:externals.

This behavior can be (only generally) deactivated, see https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin, chapter "lightweight checkout capability for Subversion on Multibranch Pipeline projects and Externals support"

Comment: If possible, can you please share details on how to do Multibranch pipeline with SVN? I am not able to find any samples anywhere